# Solr compatible fields

Tags: solr

Under http://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/other-parsers.html#OtherParsers-JoinQueryParser it states:

"The join operation is done on a term basis, so the "from" and "to" fields must use compatible field types. For example: joining between a StrField and a TrieIntField will not work, likewise joining between a StrField and a TextField that uses LowerCaseFilterFactory will only work for values that are already lower cased in the string field."

Is there a lit of compatible field types?  Is it just string (accounting for case) to string when doing a join?  Int/long to Int/long?

thnx, 
Christoph

Answer (score 1):

The key point is that the tokens after indexing has to be exactly the same. Since this can change between field types based on settings and between versions, the only safe assumption is that `StrField` and `TextField` will remain compatible.

If you need other fields to be compatible, index their content to a string field as well as the regular field type.